# getting address as output when multiplying two matrices

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication

hi I have a question about multiplying two matrices

This is the code that I wrote

```
#include <stdio.h>

void getData(int matrix1[20][20], int matrix2[20][20], int row1, int row2, int col1, int col2);
void  matrixMult(int matrix1[20][20], int matrix2[20][20], int matrix3[20][20], int row1, int row2, int col1, int col2);

int main(void)
{
    // global declarations
    int matrix1[20][20];
    int matrix2[20][20];
    int matrix3[20][20];
    int row1;
    int row2;
    int col1;
    int col2;


       printf("Enter first matrix dimension: ");
       scanf("%d %d", &row1, &col1);
       printf("%d x %d\n", row1, col1);
       printf("Enter first matrix dimension: ");
       scanf("%d %d", &row2, &col2);    
       printf("%d x %d\n", row2, col2);
       printf("\n");

       if(col1 == row2)
       {
            getData(matrix1, matrix2, row1, row2, col1, col2);   
            matrixMult(matrix1, matrix2, matrix3, row1, row2, col1, col2);
       }




    return 0;
}

void getData(int matrix1[20][20], int matrix2[20][20], int row1, int row2, int col1, int col2)
{ 
    // local declarations
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    printf("Enter number by row and column: ");
    printf("\n");
    // input first matrix
    for(i = 0; i < row1; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < col1; j++)
        {

            scanf("%d", &matrix1[i][j]);
        }
    // reset i and j
    i = 0;
    j = 0;

    printf("Enter number by row and column: ");
    printf("\n");
    // intput second matrix
    for(i = 0; i < row2; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < col2; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &matrix1[i][j]);
        }


    return;
}


void  matrixMult(int matrix1[20][20], int matrix2[20][20], int matrix3[20][20], int row1, int row2, int col1, int col2)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < row1; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < col2; j++)
        {
            for (k= 0; k < row2; k++)
            {
                sum += matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k][j]; 
            }   

            matrix3[i][j] = sum;
            sum = 0; // set sum to 0
        }
    }
    //reset i and j
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    printf("product of matrix 1 and 2: ");
    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0; i < row1; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < col2; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", matrix3[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return;
}
```

the output does not print the value after multiplication instead its print out the address of those values

```
Enter first matrix dimension: 2 2
2 x 2
Enter first matrix dimension: 2 3
2 x 3

Enter number by row and column:
1 2
2 3
Enter number by row and column:
1 2 3
1 2 4
product of matrix 1 and 2:
40829548        41222770        41615992

40829548        41222770        41615992
```

what wrong with the code, did i do something wrong when passing matrix1, matrix2 and matrix3 to the matrixMult function ?

thank in advance.

---

I re-wrote the code in main only, but this time the last column of the product matrix still print out garbage

```
 #include <stdio.h>



int main(void)
{
    // global declarations
    int matrix1[20][20];
    int matrix2[20][20];
    int matrix3[20][20];
    int row1;
    int row2;
    int col1;
    int col2;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int sum = 0;   

       printf("Enter first matrix dimension: ");
       scanf("%d %d", &row1, &col1);
       printf("%d x %d\n", row1, col1);
       printf("Enter first matrix dimension: ");
       scanf("%d %d", &row2, &col2);    
       printf("%d x %d\n", row2, col2);
       printf("\n");

       if(col1 != row2)
       {
            printf("Matrices cannot be multiply!");
       }

       else
       {
           printf("Enter first matrix: ");
            printf("\n");
            for(i = 0; i < row1; i++)
                for(j = 0; j < col1; j++)
                    scanf("%d", &matrix1[i][j]);

            printf("Enter second matrix: ");
            printf("\n");
            for(i = 0; i < row1; i++)
                for(j = 0; j < col1; j++)
                    scanf("%d", &matrix2[i][j]);

            for(i = 0; i < row1; i++)
            {
                for(j = 0; j < col2; j++)
                {
                    for (k= 0; k < row2; k++)
                    {
                        sum += matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k][j];
                    }

                    matrix3[i][j] = sum;
                    sum = 0; // set sum to 0
                }
            }

            printf("product of matrix 1 and 2: ");
            printf("\n");
            for(i = 0; i < row1; i++)
            {
                for(j = 0; j < col2; j++)
                {
                    printf("%d\t", matrix3[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }


       }


    return 0;
}
```

this is my output

```
Enter first matrix dimension: 2 2
2 x 2
Enter first matrix dimension: 2 3
2 x 3

Enter first matrix:
1 2
3 4
Enter second matrix:
2 1 4
2 5 6
product of matrix 1 and 2:
10      5       1717986916
22      11      -1717986924
```

why does the last column print out garbage?

Comment: I usually put parenthesis in such a statement &(matrix1[i][j]), more for clarity than other, since the operator precedence would handle it correctly anyway... http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm

Comment: Your code works fine of course after the changes I made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code lies here :

```
printf("Enter number by row and column: ");
    printf("\n");
    // intput second matrix
    for(i = 0; i < row2; i++)
      for(j = 0; j < col2; j++)
        {
          scanf("%d", &matrix1[i][j]);// you were entering the values in matrix1 and leaving the matri2 blank so make it matrix2 instead. 
        }
```

Change this :

`scanf("%d", &matrix1[i][j]);`

to this :

`scanf("%d", &matrix2[i][j]);`

Comment: Arrays are not copied: you are passing a copy, but of the address, so you DO write in the original matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think what you see printed are addresses: your printf statement seems correct. You have to check the function in which you are filling the matrix, the error is probably there. It can help if you reset the destination matrix at the beginning of your program.

I also suggest that you print your input matrix after reading them.